# Sony Bravia TV Color Saturation Broken After Macbook Air HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook, hdmi, colors, tv

Recently I bought a HDMI cable to connect my Macbook Air Retina to my Sony Bravia TV, which supports 1080p. The display transferred, but the color saturation is off. The saturation is more red and orange while the resolution is lower than expected. Not only that, the issue persists even after I unplugged the HDMI cable. Even when I have no other input devices and just watch cable TV programs, the color saturation problem remains. 
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I apologize if this is not the right place to ask and would appreciate a pointer to the right place.